# How are the FAQ questions chosen?

Tags: support

Go to any site, and click the `Questions` button, then the `FAQ` tab:

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=faq)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=faq)
- [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions?sort=faq)

(all sites have them, those are just the examples)

So, how are those questions chosen? By the number of duplicates? I don't think it's by the number of views, the Ask Ubuntu one has a few questions that have only about 100 views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tooltip on that page says:

```
Questions with the most links
```

It's not restricted to "closed as dup" links - any question from the same site that is mentioned (in the question, answers or comments) gets "Linked".