# What does 'questions with most links' mean?

Tags: support, tags, questions, linked-questions, frequent-tab

On Stack Overflow, 'FAQ' questions are "questions with most links". What does 'links' mean here?

Does it mean the questions contain a lot of URL links or the question has a lot of comments, answers and discussions?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/how-exactly-are-faq-questions-chosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the number of times that question has been linked in other questions or answers around the site. All of the links to the question are displayed in the right column under the "Linked" heading.

Comment: hi, what does 'has been linked' mean ? does it mean other questions or answers cited this question or that the other questions or answers contain a url to this question ?

Comment: It simply means that a link to that question was posted somewhere in another question. I believe even a link posted in the comments will link the two questions together.